# How to suppress default constructor on a generated dynamic type

Tags: .net, codegen

When creating a dynamic type in .NET, a default constructor is generated. How do I suppress that?

```
var typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType(
    type.FullName,
    TypeAttributes.NotPublic | TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is documented in the "Remarks Section" of the [TypeBuilder.DefineConstructor Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dda9whaz(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks).

> If you do not define a constructor for your dynamic type, a default
>   constructor is provided automatically, and it calls the default
>    constructor of the base class.
>
> If you define a constructor for your dynamic type, a default
>   constructor is not provided. You have the following options for
>   providing a default constructor in addition to the constructor you
>   defined:

- > If you want a default constructor that simply calls the default
  >   constructor of the base class, you can use the
  >   DefineDefaultConstructor method to create one (and optionally restrict
  >   access to it). Do not provide an implementation for this default
  >   constructor. If you do, an exception is thrown when you try to use the
  >   constructor. No exception is thrown when the CreateType method is
  >   called.
- > If you want a default constructor that does something more than simply
  >   calling the default constructor of the base class, or that calls
  >   another constructor of the base class, or that does something else
  >   entirely, you must use the TypeBuilder.DefineConstructor method to
  >   create one, and provide your own implementation.

This behavior is no different than if you define a class without explicitly defining a default constructor; the compiler generates a public default constructor that calls the base constructor.

If you want a private default constructor, then:

```
 ConstructorBuilder ctor = typeBuilder.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Private);
```

**Edit:**

In the comments, it was mentioned that a `static` class does not have a constructor.  After a bit of back and forth with Reflector, I determined that the following will create a static dynamic class with same default attributes generated by c#.

```
public void Test()
{
AssemblyName asmName = new AssemblyName("TestAsmStatic");
AssemblyBuilder ab = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(asmName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
ModuleBuilder mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule(asmName.Name, asmName.Name + ".dll");
TypeBuilder tb = mb.DefineType("StaticType", TypeAttributes.NotPublic | TypeAttributes.Sealed | TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit | TypeAttributes.Abstract);
Type t = tb.CreateType();
ab.Save(asmName.Name + ".dll");

ConstructorInfo[] ci = t.GetConstructors((System.Reflection.BindingFlags)(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static));
Console.WriteLine(ci.Length.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of this documentation. But I don't want a constructor *at all*. C# lets you do this with a `static class` (either that, or perhaps it generates a private default ctor if the CLR requires it for some reason). 
I suppose I can follow the docs you mentioned to make the default ctor private. I was just hoping to not define one at all.

Comment: @AndrewArnott, good point about a static class.  I've never tried to emit one nor do I know if it is possible.  I'll have take a look at that.

Comment: I just confirmed via ildasm that C#'s `static class`'s do not include a private default constructor. So CLR evidently doesn't mandate it. The only question is whether .NET offers a way with their `TypeBuilder` to create one.

Comment: @AndrewArnott, see my edit for a static class example.

Comment: Awesome. It looks like `Abstract|Sealed` is the trick. thanks.